# UTM Coordinate Mapping Across Zones

Tags: coordinate-system, visualisation, utm

I am building an application that requires me to plot UTM coordinates on a chart using CSV data. I am given two UTM coordinates for each record, although I would like the application to handle zone crossing with little loss of accuracy. I am not given a UTM zone, only the coordinates. Is it possible to handle UTM zone crossing without the information of which zone you are in given zone? Only given coordinates such as 539594.4,9071398.0 (probably not outside zone)?

Comment: I would try and find out about the source of the data and how they were collected. Someone surely has some metadata somewhere. That's pretty important. What are you plotting the points on? A web map, plotting in a desktop GIS?

Answer (score 5):

No, because UTM coordinates are repeated in each zone. If the data was localized--only covered the eastern and western parts of two zones, you might be able to do it because you could segregate the values into the two zones. If you had 539594, 9071398 and 493840, 9198483 are these in the same zone or in zones 31 and 32 or 10 and 11?